# ORA-01292: Can't access log file with log miner while using online catalog

Tags: oracle, logminer

I'm currently trying to add logminer to my Oracle database.
The goal is to use le online catalog but when i use :

EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);

to start the log miner i get this error :

ORA-01292: aucun fichier journal n'est indique pour la session LogMiner actuelle

ORA-01292: no log file for current LogMiner session.

Do you have any clue on this ?

Do i need to add a log file even if i use the online catalog ?

Thanks,